# Prep data (separate/split cells into rows)

Tags: spotfire

I have a large dataset which format does not fit my analysis, I have an issue:

Several columns contains information delimited by semicolon (e.g. London;bruxelles;copenhagen)

I would need these to be splitted into rows (not columns)

This means I would have a row for each of the cities above for instance

This steps are possible in powerbi, does anybody know how to do this in spotfire?

Thanks
Kristoffer

Comment: You should post only one question per post (you can post multiple questions at the same time), it is better for us to answer at one question at a time. It is also easier for people to, later, find an answer to their similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! - I have changed

Answer (score 0):

The operation you want to do is quite heavy, there is no Spotfire built-in function to achieve what you want to do. I would suggest you to use a R script (aka `datafunction`) to make this. Note that you need the package `tidyr`, don't forget to put it in your script!

Assuming that `df` is the parameter of the script associated to your table, `cities` is the column you want to modify and `sep` is the separator:

```
 df <- separate_rows(df, cities, sep = ';')
```