# split column values in the plot setting - spotfire

Tags: split, spotfire

I am fairly new to spotfire and I have a basic question.

I have a table like this (2 columns, in the price column the values are separated by comma and I don't have for each supermarket the same number of prices):

```
supermarket  price
A            10,20,5,40,50
B            2,40,15
C            30,70,3,80,32,54,89,110
D            16,89,3,23,37,19
```

I would like to create a scatterplot, where on the x-axis there are the different supermarket and on the y-axis the different prices. I have no idea on how split these value (and convert them to numerical values) just in the plot (so using 'Edit Expression' feature). I looked at the spotfire documentation but I found only this information (https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-cloud/latest/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire_bauthor-consumer_usersguide/bauthcons/topics/en-US/splitting_a_column.html) which is not useful for my task.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a similar question, creating a transformed table using a TERR script might help you:

[Prep data (separate/split cells into rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795945/prep-data-separate-split-cells-into-rows)

If you don't want to use a TERR data function, there could be an alternative via an Iron Python script.
I wanted to create the calculated columns then apply an unpivot transformation, unfortunately unpivot does not work with calculated columns.
So my solution would be to create a set of calculated columns via the script, then also create a document property that contains the column names to use
in a scatter plot (so you don't need the unpivot).

The script (it looks complicated but it is simple really):

-find the maximum possible number of prices hidden in the [price] column;

-create as many calculated columns as the max number of prices (some will be empty);

-fill a document property to contain the list of these new columns to use in the plot

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import CalculatedColumn, IndexSet, DataValueCursor

#list of existing columns in data table called "data"
mytablename='data'
mytable = Document.Data.Tables[mytablename]
cols = mytable.Columns

#------------------------------
#max_n_prices is calculated from all rows
rowsToInclude = IndexSet(mytable.RowCount,True)
n_values = list()
cursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(mytable.Columns['price'])
for row in mytable.GetRows(rowsToInclude,cursor):
    price = cursor.CurrentValue
    n_values.append (len(price.split(','))) #count the number of elements after splitting by comma

max_n_prices = max(n_values)+1

#------------------------------
#add calculated columns returning different split positions
#if we run out of commas on a specific row, it will simply return an empty cell
new_cols=[]
for i in range(1,max_n_prices):
    new_col_name = "price"+str(i)
    new_cols.append(new_col_name)   
    try:
        cols.AddCalculatedColumn(new_col_name,"Integer(split([price],',',"+str(i)+"))")     
    except:
        pass #if the column exists, do nothing

#----------------------------
#now create a document property with all the column names to plot
new_cols1 = ["["+mytablename+"].["+x+"]" for x in new_cols]
new_cols1=', '.join(new_cols1)

#property must already exist
Document.Properties['plotColumns']=new_cols1
```

Run it, then use the document property 'plotColumns' as Y axis in the plot. The X axis needs to be <[supermarket] NEST [Axis.Default.Names]>